# React-slick carousel - autoplay not working in child component while triggering it with prop from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I m using React. I am trying to implement a carousel and I tried to trigger auto play option(props for Slider literally) in *react-slick*, the autoplay in react-slick is not working.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/2v7j4ml670  -  here is an example implement
Help Me out!!!!!!

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had used react-slick 0.23.1 which it doesn't work

Later I tried with react-slick 0.21.0 it did work

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give a reference to the  tag.

```
<Slider ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)}>
 ...
</Slider>
```

You can use the slickPause() & slickPlay() functions

```
play() {
  this.slider.slickPlay();
}

pause() {
  this.slider.slickPause();
}
```

https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/examples/AutoPlayMethods.js